# laravel cascade not working?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a ticketsystem with laravel. But when I remove a ticket the reactions don't go away?

This is my migration of the pivot table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reactions_ticket',function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->integer('ticket_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('ticket_id')->references('id')->on('ticket')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->integer('reactions_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('reactions_id')->references('id')->on('reactions')->onDelete('cascade');
            });
    }
```

And this is my reaction table:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('reactions',function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
                $table->text('content');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
    }
```

and my ticket table:

```
   public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('ticket',function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('slug')->nullable();

                $table->integer('ticketid')->unsigned();

                $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

                $table->integer('subject_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('subject_id')->references('id')->on('subject')->onDelete('cascade');

                $table->integer('websites_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('websites_id')->references('id')->on('websites')->onDelete('cascade');

                $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('status')->onDelete('cascade');

                $table->text('content');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

What am I doing wrong>?

Comment: Do you have softDeleting on?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why should I do that? I just want to remove everything related with that ticket. When I go to the laravel docs it;s telling me this about softDeleting: "When soft deleting a model, it is not actually removed from your database." That's not what I want.

Comment: If you have softDeleting on your `tickets` model, calling `delete()` on one won't delete its relationships.

Comment: Oke, but checked it and I don't have softDeleting in my Ticket model.

Comment: It looks like if you were to delete a reactions_ticket both the ticket and reaction would be deleted, but if you delete a ticket I don't see where the cascade would occur.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would always prefer to handle such actions by myself instead of let id be done by MySQL.

You could use laravels event-handler inside your `Ticket` model.

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();
    static::deleting(function($ticket) {
        // delete related stuff ;)
        $reaction_ids = $ticket->reactions()->lists('id');
        Reaction::whereIn($reaction_ids)->delete();
    });
}
```

So you still have (if you want/need) the advantage of softdelete and more controll.

Answer (score 0):

You have a many to many join between reactions and tickets. Therefore a ticket can have many reactions and a reaction could have many tickets. If you delete a ticket I would not expect to have the reactions deleted because those reactions could be attached to other tickets that are not deleted.

What will be deleted are the entries in the pivot table for that ticket. If you wanted to clean up all reactions that no longer have a ticket attached, that would be a separate task, mysql won't cascade that for you.

Your table names are not standard, Btw. They should be tickets, reactions, and reaction_ticket for the pivot table.